# How to delete a irrelevant facebook comment from my website(Asp.net)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

How to delete a irrelevant fb comment from my website. What i am doing is as:

```
 <div id="fb-root">
    </div>
```

making myself as admin :

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="myfbid"/>

<script>    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MyID";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Placed where i want FB-Comment box to be rendered:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="mysiteurl.com" data-width="600"></div>
```

My basic question is how can i delete a comment which is vulgar and publicly visible ? Although i have set myself as moderator in tools then also i am not able to delete other people comment(facebook) from my website i can only mark them as spam but others can easily see the comment on thier individual login. Thank You

Comment: So you want to erase the comment from their fb? Or just from your site?

Comment: from my site that is using FB comment plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following method:

Put this in you Document in the head section:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="jayeshjain24ec" /> //username of moderater
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.something.com/" />
```

---

step 1) Go to this url : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

---

step 2) Enter your URL and click on debug.
In case if there is anything to be corrected,it will be mentioned here.

---

step 3)Correct all the warnings.Check the Scraped URL link at the bottom.Make sure it gets all the required Meta tags.

You will get a moderation option on your website once everything is ok.

### ALTERNATE SOLUTION:

Give yourself admin rights for the app(there is an option in settings).

go to this url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue